# Text display in local language in PDF report

Tags: ofbiz

I developed application using ofbiz frame work, now I need to customize application, content display in PDF reports also in local language.

Can anyone please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

In OFBiz the localisation is done through the *lab*.xml files.

BTW for further questions, please subscribe to the user ML and use your email client:
http://ofbiz.apache.org/mailing-lists.html

You will get a better support and it's more fair to share with everybody
The wider the audience the better the answers you might get

Thanks

Jacques